# MongoDB update strange behaviour

Tags: mongodb

This is the document before being edited.

```
{
"EstadoPedido" : 10,
"IdPedido" : 3113,
"Meta" : {
    "DataAlt" : "2018-05-25 15:33:21",
    "DataCri" : "2018-05-25 15:28:51",
    "IdUserAlt" : "83",
    "IdUserCri" : 83,
    "UserAlt" : "AAA",
    "UserCri" : "AAA",
    "sDataAlt" : ISODate("2018-05-25T15:33:21.000Z"),
    "sDataCri" : ISODate("2018-05-25T15:28:51.000Z")
},
```

}

And after being edited the field "EstadoPedido" should be 20 or 30:

```
{
    "EstadoPedido" : 30,
    "IdPedido" : 3113,
    "Meta" : {
        "DataAlt" : "2018-05-25 15:33:21",
        "DataCri" : "2018-05-25 15:28:51",
        "IdUserAlt" : "83",
        "IdUserCri" : 83,
        "UserAlt" : "AAA",
        "UserCri" : "AAA",
        "sDataAlt" : ISODate("2018-05-25T15:33:21.000Z"),
        "sDataCri" : ISODate("2018-05-25T15:28:51.000Z")
    },
}
```

EDIT//

This is how I call the function and pass the parameters:

```
$onapp->put('/pedido/setAnulado/:idPedido', function($idpedido){
    $P = new Pedido();
    $R = $P->setAnulado($idpedido);

    $M_Ped = new \Oncargo\MongoApi\Pedido();
    $ret = $M_Ped->setEstado($idpedido, 30);

    echo json_encode($R);
});
```

$P = new Pedido() is the Class to save the object to SQL Server using Propel framework.

$M_Ped = new \Oncargo\MongoApi\Pedido() is the Mongo Class object to save.

And that $M_Ped->setEstado goes to here:

```
public function setEstado($idPedido, $estado) {
    $this->IdPedido = $idPedido;
    $this->Estado = $estado;
    $r = $this->_mudaEstado($idPedido, $estado);
    return $r;
}
```

which then goes back to the update and the full function is:

```
private function _mudaEstado($idPedido, $estadoPedido) {
    $userNome = $this->userData['Nome'];
    $c = $this->db->selectCollection('pedidos');

    if (date('I')) { $_dst = 3600; } else { $_dst = 0; }

    $DataAlt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $sDataAlt = new \MongoDate(strtotime($DataAlt) + $_dst);
    $criteria = array('IdPedido' => $idPedido);
    $update = array(
        '$set' => array(
            'EstadoPedido'          => $estadoPedido,
            'Meta.IdUserAlt'        => $this->userData['IdUser'],
            'Meta.UserAlt'          => $userNome,
            'Meta.DataAlt'          => $DataAlt,
            'Meta.sDataAlt'         => $sDataAlt
        )
    );
    $r = $c->update($criteria, $update);
    return $r;
}
```

EDIT 2 //

I've also done a print_r($update) for both scenarios, 20 (which is working) and 30 (which is not working) and the data is the same:

Output of the working bit:

```
Array
(
    [$set] => Array
        (
            [EstadoPedido] => 20
            [Meta.IdUserAlt] => 83
            [Meta.UserAlt] => AAA
            [Meta.DataAlt] => 2018-05-28 14:26:07
            [Meta.sDataAlt] => MongoDate Object
                (
                    [sec] => 1527517567
                    [usec] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

And this is the output of the non working update variable:

```
Array
(
    [$set] => Array
        (
            [EstadoPedido] => 30
            [Meta.IdUserAlt] => 83
            [Meta.UserAlt] => AAA
            [Meta.DataAlt] => 2018-05-28 14:28:21
            [Meta.sDataAlt] => MongoDate Object
                (
                    [sec] => 1527517701
                    [usec] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

As you can see, both queries are the same and one is working and the other isn't.

Comment: It seems that there is no document matching IdPedido 30.

Comment: But in this case IdPedido is not 30, IdPedido = 3113. State 30 is what I want to set in EstadoPedido (which is currently 20)

Comment: `n: 0` means "not matched". You seem confused here because you keep using the word "set" but this is just a "query" condition. You're asking for it "match where 20" and not "change from 20 to 30" which would be something completely different from what you are doing. You still "match where 20", it's just you need to `$set` that same field to 30, and you're just not doing that anywhere.

Comment: @NeilLunn that does not make sense, because when I set it from state 10 to state 20, it is working fine, and I'm not searching for state 20. I'm just setting that IdPedido to state 20. So it should work the same for state 30

Comment: The only thing not making sense here is the question. Throw away the pictures and half the code here and show two documents only, and using the JSON view and NOT pictures. Show the document data before you update it, and then show what the document data needs to look like "after" you update it. Then show the update statement you "think" takes from from A to B and then we can clearly tell you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: You've cut out the "query" or `$criteria` part of the `update()` statement. What we keep telling you is that criteria needs to be looking for `"EstadoPedido" : 10` but you appear to be putting `20` or `30` in that part. Show what values you "think" you are passing in, but it looks for all purposes that "criteria" as the wrong data in it.

Comment: @NeilLunn thanks for your help! I've already updated the code. Hope it was this.

Answer (score 0):

It's solved! It was a newbie error! Everything was working fine and the update query is 100% correct! The only thing I was missing was to cast the $idPedido to Integer because the parameter was being passed as String. Now it is working as it should.

```
private function _mudaEstado($idPedido, $estadoPedido) {
    $userNome = $this->userData['Nome'];
    $c = $this->db->selectCollection('pedidos');

    if (date('I')) { $_dst = 3600; } else { $_dst = 0; }

    $DataAlt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $sDataAlt = new \MongoDate(strtotime($DataAlt) + $_dst);
    $criteria = array('IdPedido' => (int)$idPedido); // Was missing the cast to int
    $update = array(
        '$set' => array(
            'EstadoPedido'          => $estadoPedido,
            'Meta.IdUserAlt'        => $this->userData['IdUser'],
            'Meta.UserAlt'          => $userNome,
            'Meta.DataAlt'          => $DataAlt,
            'Meta.sDataAlt'         => $sDataAlt
        )
    );
    $r = $c->update($criteria, $update);
    return $r;
}
```

Thanks everyone for your precious help! Hope this can actually help someone else.